# Making multiple sub directories easily

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, script, batch-file

I have a folder with 900 sub folders within it, (Members names) I need to add three folders to each.....2018, 2019 and 2020. I cannot figure the proper syntax to get the sub directories created in each folder.

Answer (score 1):

#### I cannot figure the proper syntax to get the sub directories created in each folder.

Something like the following should do the trick.

From the command line:

```
for /d %i in (*) do md "%i\2018" && md "%i\2019" && md "%i\2020"
```

In a batch file:

```
for /d %%i in (*) do md "%%i\2018" && md "&%i\2019" && md "%%i\2020"
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [for /d](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) - Conditionally perform a command on several Directories/Folders.
- [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) - Redirection operators.

Comment: Or `for /d %A in (*) do @for %B in (2018 2019 2020) do md "%%A\%%B"`

Comment: @dbenham That's why I said mod edit. Fixed for you.

Comment: Ooh - I wasn't aware of that privilege!! How do I access that feature?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use PowerShell

```
cd <PARENT_DIRECTORY>
ls | foreach { for ($i=2018; $i -lt 2021; $i++) { new-item "$_\$i" -itemtype directory -force }}
```

I've tested it and can confirm it works:

[image]

Comment: The `-force` parameter suppresses error messages when `Get-ChildItem` also iterates file names, better exclude files with either `-Directory` parameter of gci or insert an `| Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer}`